# how to use sed to replace a number with letters

Tags: text-processing, sed, files

I have a text file that contains the following lines.

```
Maynard G. Krebs , ss #111−22−3333, the goofy but lovable beatnik in The Many
Loves of Dobie Gillis. None of the show's episodes ever specified Gilligan's
```

How do i use sed to replace the number `#111-22-3333` with `xxx-xx-xxxx`?

This is what i have in my sed script:
`s/([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})/xxx-xx-xxxx/g` 
I run it with `sed -f redact.sed redact.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Drop the parenthesis, or Sed will try to match a parenthesis in your file.
- `{n}` is part of extended regular expressions. Give Sed the `-E` flag to enable them (`sed -Ef redact.sed redact.txt`), or escape each brace.
- Notice your file contains some sort of en-dash (0xE28892): It is not the good old 0x2D ASCII `-`, so that you would need to put it in the Sed expression too.

  ```
  sed 's/[0-9]\{3\}−[0-9]\{2\}−[0-9]\{4\}/xxx-xx-xxxx/g'
  sed -E 's/[0-9]{3}−[0-9]{2}−[0-9]{4}/xxx-xx-xxxx/g'
  ```